Wrapping imperitive APi in React component (OpenLayers)
I am wrapping a non-react DOM API (OpenLayers) in a react component. I call the API in a useCallback to ensure it only gets called when the DOM element it is manipulating gets mounted.
function MapComponent({ ...divProps }) {
  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    ...

    const overlay = new Overlay({
      element: popup,
      autoPan: {
        animation: {
          duration: 250,
        },
      },
    });
    ...

    const map = new Map({
      target: node,
      layers: [imageLayer, markersLayer],
      view: new View({
        projection: projection
      }),
      overlays: [overlay],
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} {...divProps} />
    </>
  );
}

This works fine. However, I now want to call a method on overlay based on the a prop that gets passed in (I maintain a selected feature in state outside of the component, and pass it in, and based on the feature I position the overlay).
How would I be able to do that? I need to be able to somehow get to the overlay value that is inside the callback function and manipulate it on a props change.
